# Printing get parameters from express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Node.js express middleware is running on parse.com.

For the following request: `http://gopaces.com/echo/test123?getParam1=AAA` handled by the following code in app.js:

```
app.get('/echo/:reqParam', function(req, res) {
    console.log("reqParam " + req.params.reqParam);
    console.log("getParam1 " + req.params.getParam1);
});
```

The following is printed

```
E2014-07-30T09:20:41.511Z]v92 Ran custom endpoint with:
  Input:{"method":"GET","url":"/echo/test123?getParam1=AAA","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept-language":"en-us","host":"gopaces.com","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/538.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/538.46","version":"HTTP/1.1","x-forwarded-proto":"http"}}
  Result: success/error was not called
I2014-07-30T09:20:41.617Z]reqParam test123
I2014-07-30T09:20:41.831Z]getParam1 undefined
```

Where as I would expect to see

```
I2014-07-30T09:20:41.617Z]reqParam test123
I2014-07-30T09:20:41.831Z]getParam1 AAA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log("getParam1 " + req.query.getParam1);
```

http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#req.query

Answer (score 0):

Your named parameters relate to the path of the URL, not the query string variables. Your query string variables will not be accessible in the `params` object, but instead in the `req.query` object.

Answer (score 0):

For reference completeness

For the given request

```
curl -X PUT -d 'viaBody=bodyValue' 'http://gopaces.com/echo/parameterValue?viaQuery=queryValue'
```

This code

```
app.put('/echo/:viaParameter', function(req, res) {
    console.log("viaParameter " + req.params.viaParameter);
    console.log("viaQuery " + req.query.viaQuery);
    console.log("viaBody " + req.body.viaBody);
});
```

Will dump the values

```
I2014-07-30T11:21:39.336Z]viaQuery queryValue
I2014-07-30T11:21:39.337Z]viaBody bodyValue
I2014-07-30T11:21:39.338Z]viaParameter parameterValue
```